Syncing Audio from MPEG-2 video to MPEG-4 Video After encode LPCM 5.1 to True-HD Master Audio
I was having nightmare trying to make sync to movie that I have but found better audio in LPCM 6912 kbp's so I tried my best to make it DTS-HD Master Audio 5.1 and all worked fine. I muxed new DTS file to movie and all sounds great, as tey start audio at exactly same moment, to the time in the movie as exactly in 02:30:00 when it's delayed -1100 ms for 3 sec, and then -2850 ms to the end of whole movie.
Both video have different length, approximately that covers that delay in sum:
Video source:
Name:                   00000.MPLS
Length:                 3:03:05.099 (h:m:s.ms)
Size:                   43,920,433,152 bytes
Total Bitrate:          31.99 Mbps

VIDEO:

Codec                   Bitrate             Description     
-----                   -------             -----------     
MPEG-4 AVC Video        24077 kbps          1080p / 23.976 fps / 16:9 / High Profile 4.1

Audio source:
Name:                   00011.MPLS
Length:                 3:03:09.061 (h:m:s.ms)
Size:                   42,218,323,968 bytes
Total Bitrate:          30.73 Mbps

VIDEO:

Codec                   Bitrate             Description     
-----                   -------             -----------     
MPEG-2 Video            20832 kbps          1080p / 23.976 fps / 16:9

I started to use different spread in time MKVNixTool, and changing the fps of DTS video but that was all for nothing (tried also different versions of true hd with drop tc etc.). I never such a problem, when suddenly audio change sync so dramatically in middle of couple of seconds. Maybe someone with more experience can help me what can and if I can do something about that?
I tried different audio from 2cd source where LPCM is, and problem shows exactly in the same moment when watching movie after merging it all.
Ohh, almost forgot. This is the mediainfo for True-HD:
General
Complete name                            : DTSENC.dtshd
Format                                   : DTS XLL
Format/Info                              : Digital Theater Systems
Commercial name                          : DTS-HD Master Audio
File size                                : 4.58 GiB
Duration                                 : 3 h 3 min
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 3 576 kb/s
Maximum Overall bit rate                 : 4 901 kb/s

Audio

Format                                   : DTS XLL
Format/Info                              : Digital Theater Systems
Commercial name                          : DTS-HD Master Audio
Duration                                 : 3 h 3 min
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 3 576 kb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 4 901 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel layout                           : C L R Ls Rs LFE
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Bit depth                                : 24 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossless
Stream size                              : 4.57 GiB (100%)
Time code                                : 00:00:00:00

What may be the problem, and how can i fix it. I don't want to compress it for sure, as it is as good as can be, or may I be wrong? Thanks for all help you can find and share with me. I am trying to do this from, a couple of good days spending few hours a day on it.
Cheers all!
I cover all what I did in above format, so I am sure someone will get something from it. If there is any more info needed to help solve this problem I am glad to post it here.
PS: Video is in 23.976 fps (both)
